# Adding input fields in Javascript with onclick button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Im always used to using jquery or other javascript frameworks but right now I have no frameworks to use so i wanted to see if anyone knows how i can do this in straight javascript if possible.

Basically i have a div like this

```
<input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />

<div id="room_fileds">
    <div class='label'>Room 1:</div>
    <div class="content">
        <span>Width: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[]" value="" /><small>(ft)</small> X </span>
        <span>Length: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" namae="length[]" value="" /><small>(ft)</small</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i need one is when the add more button is clicked i need to basically add more width and length fields either creating a entire structure like the one above with all the divs or just inserting new span tag with the fields below the existing ones.

I know how to do it with jquery or prototype framework but unfortunatley I cannot use any frameworks for this. Does anyone have any idea how to do it. I would post code iv done for this but I dont even know where to beging.

Comment: Simply use the `innerHTML` property of the wrapping div, i.e. `document.getElementById('someIdYouAssignToTheDiv').innerHTML += '<span><input ..../></span>';`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `innerHTML` property to add content. Add a `id="wrapper"` to the `div` surrounding your `span` elements and then you can do

```
var dummy = '<span>Label: <input type="text"><small>(ft)</small></span>\r\n';
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += dummy;
```

Of course you don't need the `id` and can use other DOM methods to get to the `div`, but I find using `id`s easier and cleaner. Here's a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2t9Dh/)

Also note that you shouldn't inline your css code, neither attach your javascript calls directly inside the DOM elements. Separating DOM, Javascript and CSS will make your life easier.

Comment: This works fine but i have one issue. When i click the button it adds the fields just fine but seems to clear the fields that are already filled in. What would be causing this. Iv never seen this happen

Comment: You can use `createElement` and `appendChild` to avoid this. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2t9Dh/1/

Answer (score 9):

Don't need create new room?.

```
var room = 1;
function add_fields() {
    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Room ' + room +':</div><div class="content"><span>Width: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[]" value="" /><small>(ft)</small> X</span><span>Length: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" namae="length[]" value="" /><small>(ft)</small></span></div>';

    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nj4N4/7/

Comment: Your answer does not provide any actual code and just links to an external provider. Also, I fail to see how your answer adds anything substantial the the answers already given.

Answer (score 3):

just use the `innerHTML` like this:

btw I changed div `class="content"` to `id="content"` you can add new id if you prefer.

```
function add_fields() {
   var d = document.getElementById("content");

   d.innerHTML += "<br /><span>Width: <input type='text'style='width:48px;'value='' /><small>(ft)</small></span> X <span>Length: <input type='text' style='width:48px'  value='' /><small>(ft)</small</span>";
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/oxokiq/5/edit