# Js to duplicate section of fields and rename for form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I need to dynamically add fields to a form page so users can add additional entries of the same form.  It's a form to describe units in a subdivision, and the number of units and types vary.  I need to add like a plus button using js that will allow them to add fields, and for those field names to be incremented I guess so they are all separate inputs into the handler.  What i have for html is as follows

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <link href="exhibitb.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chicago Low-Income Housing Trust Fund</title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <form action="/clihtf.php" method="post">
        <div class="bold2">  Exhibit B</div>
        <div class="bold"> DSU</div>
             <section>
  <p>
        <span>unit: </span>
        <br>
      </label>
      <input type="number" id="totUni" name="totUni" >
          <p>
      <label for="nbr">
        <span>nbr: </span>  
      </label>
             <br>
      <input type="number" id="nbr" name="nbr" >
    </p>
          <p>
      <label for="trsu">
        <span>trsu: </span>  
      </label>
             <br>
      <input type="number" id="trsu" name="trsu">
    </p>
          <p>
      <label for="mtpr">
        <span>Mtpr: </span>  
      </label>
             <br>
      <input type="text" id="mtpr" name="mtpr">
    </p>
          <p>
      <label for="msasu">
        <span>Monthly SAU: </span>  
      </label>
             <br>
      <input type="text" id="msasu" name="msasu">
      <p>
      <label for="ssfga">
        <span>Social SOP (Exhibit F):
          <br> </span>  
      </label>
             <br>
      <input type="text" id="ssfga" name="ssfga">
               <p>
                  <label for="ssfgb">
    Social Service Plan (Exhibit G):
                    <br>
  <input type="text" id="ssfgb" name="ssfgb">

        <p> <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button> </p>
           </form>
  </body>
```

I have tried what is shown here: [Adding input fields in Javascript with onclick button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933037/adding-input-fields-in-javascript-with-onclick-button) and [How to create a minus and plus button to update a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125163/how-to-create-a-minus-and-plus-button-to-update-a-field) but I'm just not getting it.  I just need to literally duplicate all the fields and then have them be submit with separate names.  If this is asking too much, I am sorry.

Comment: It should be easier to do with jQuery methods. Can you add it to your project ?

Comment: Yeah doing it with jquery is fine.  If someone could explain the whole thing to me I will understand going forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to close the section tag with a /section, for example before the /form.

Then you can try with something like this :

```
var a = $('form section'); // get the section of the form
var b = $(a[0].innerHTML); // get the components to duplicate
b.find('[id]').get().forEach(e => $(e).attr('id', $(e).attr('id') + '_1')); // set "ids" of new components
b.find('[name]').get().forEach(e => $(e).attr('name', $(e).attr('name') + '_1')); // set "names"
b.find('[for]').get().forEach(e => $(e).attr('for', $(e).attr('for') + '_1')); // set "fors"
b.find('button').remove(); // do not copy the submit button
$('form section').append(b); // add new components to the section of the form
```

Take that example as a basis as it works only for one new bunch of components, you'll have to adapt it for more (or better) implementation.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you eddi.  This perfectly answers questions about another version I found by giving me another examples with different variables, thus outlining what I need to change or adapt!